# Find same value PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, I need to find out the value for each of the array which is the same.

For example,

```
   $arr1=array("a", "b", "c");
   $arr2=array("c", "d", "e");
```

Then c should be display. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)  function to find common elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$word1 =array('a', 'b','c', 'd');
$word2 =array('b', 'c', 'd', 'a');
$data = array_intersect($word1, $word2);
```

it will return a,b,d because that is common in both array

```
print_r( $data );
/* result:
    Array (
             [0] => a
             [1] => b
              [3] => d 
    ) */
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it "manually", here is one way:

```
$a1 = array("a", "b", "c");
$a2 = array("c", "d", "e");

$a3 = array();
foreach($a1 as $x) foreach($a2 as $y) if($x == $y) $a3[] = $x;

print_r($a3);
// prints:
// Array
// (
//    [0] => c
// )
```